# How to convert select-input content to string on sql query?

Tags: java, html, sql

My html form has 2 select-input field which are sent via HTTP POST as json to my java webserver API and then to my postgresql. Im having a internal error and i believe that is because the select-input json output is like this "field":["value"]
How can i tell java to read the content inside the [ ]? 
this is my query

String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO neuromotora(nervonome,latencia,amplitudedistal,amplitudeprox,velocidade,ondaf,pacienteid,ladonervo)"
                + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) RETURNING neuromotoraid";

This is the http post method on my angular frontend

```
    postData(params){
     let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-type','application/json');
     return this.http.post(this.api,params,{
     headers: headers
   }).map(
   (res:Response) => {return res.json();}
   );
```

And this is the java web server post method

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/neuromotora/")
public Response createNeuromotora(Neuromotora n) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    neuromotoraDAO dao = new neuromotoraDAO();

    dao.insert(n);

    return Response
      }
```

And this is the neuromotora java

```
  public class Neuromotora {
   private int neuromotoraid;
   private String latencia;
   private String amplitudeDistal;
   private String amplitutdeProx;
   private String nervoNome;
   private String ladoNervo;
   private String ondaF;
   private int pacienteid;
    ...getters and  setters..
     }
```

Insert method

```
 public Long insert(Neuromotora oferta) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    Long id = null;
    String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO neuromotora(nervonome,latencia,amplitudedistal,amplitudeprox,velocidade,ondaf,pacienteid,ladonervo)"
            + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) RETURNING neuromotoraid";
    try{
        PreparedStatement stmt = this.con.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        stmt.setString(1,oferta.getNervoNome());
        stmt.setString(2,oferta.getLatencia());
        stmt.setString(3,oferta.getAmplitudeDistal());
        stmt.setString(4,oferta.getAmplitutdeProx());
        stmt.setString(5, oferta.getVelocidade());
        stmt.setString(8, oferta.getOndaF());
        stmt.setInt(6,oferta.getPacienteid());
        stmt.setString(7,oferta.getLadoNervo());


        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            id = rs.getLong("neuromotoraid");
        }

        this.con.commit();        
        }
    catch(SQLException e){
        this.con.rollback();
        throw e;
        }
        return id;
        }
```

Comment: [ ] in json format means an array. Can you tell more about the way you convert your json object? Do you use jackson for example

Comment: I updated the question with the post method and the java method. I use the jersey lib

Comment: Can you add the class neuromotora and the insert method

Comment: Post all the relevant code, the JSON you're posting, and the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0):

Removing the the multiple="true" on the ion-select and adding size="1" worked for me, the input is no longer a json array.